# How to ssh into a container in which a task is running?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am creating a task from an application deployed in CF.
I can see that the task is up and running.

```
Getting tasks for app multi-process1 in org cc10a37ftrial / space dev as  abc@AAA.com

id   name          state     start time                      command
1    sample-task   RUNNING   Thu, 20 Jan 2022 17:35:03 UTC   $PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java -jar $PWD/BOOT-INF/lib/sidecarlogger-1.jar
```

Is it possible to `ssh` into the container in which this task is executing?

Comment: Did you read https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/v7/ssh.html?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer , I can `ssh` into the container of the `application` or the processes started by the application using `--process` option.  However I am starting a new `task` using command `cf run-task <APPNAME>  --name <TASK NAME> --command <'comamnd'>`. As per documentation CF runs the tasks in a new container. I am unable to log into this container. The link shared by you , does not tell how to log in to a container where the `task` is running.  Or am I not interpreting the link correctly ? [ I am using CFCLI v7]

Comment: I don't know that is feasible. The task isn't a persistent unit. I'm not sure that it gets the tiny sshd process run in it or that ssh traffic could be routed to it. You could try running a task with the command `ps aux` and see what it lists. Normally, in an application, you'll see a tiny sshd process running. If that's not running in the task container, which you'd see when running `ps aux` as a task then definitely won't work. I don't have a CF env handy to try it at the moment, sorry.

Comment: Hello @DanielMikusa , this tips was really helpful . I did not find any `sshd`  process in the container where the task is running.However I could find the following process in the container in which the main application is running. `vcap          15  0.0  0.0 715996 11252 ?        Ssl  07:04   0:00 /tmp/lifecycle/diego-sshd --allowedKeyExchanges= --address=0.0.0.0:2222 --allowUnauthenticatedClients=false --inheritDaemonEnv=true --allowedCiphers= --allowedMACs= --logLevel=fatal --debugAddr=`. So it means we can not `ssh` into the container in which the task is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to ssh into the container in which this task is executing?

That is not possible, unfortunately.

The task in Cloud Foundry isn't a persistent unit. It is meant to execute for a finite amount of time and exit. Because of that, there is no `diego-sshd` process running in the task. You can confirm this by running a task with the command `ps aux` and looking at the output.

Normally, in an application, you'll see a tiny `diego-sshd` process running.

```
vcap          15  0.0  0.0 715996 11252 ?        Ssl  07:04   0:00 /tmp/lifecycle/diego-sshd --allowedKeyExchanges= --address=0.0.0.0:2222 --allowUnauthenticatedClients=false --inheritDaemonEnv=true --allowedCiphers= --allowedMACs= --logLevel=fatal --debugAddr=
```

Thanks to [@atanu mallik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10006615/atanu-mallik) for confirming.